No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public on pipeline integration test after .NET 8 upgrade
I have upgraded my durable function app to .NET 8 isolated. The integration test is passing on localhost, but fails in the pipeline.
The request made in the integration test returns a http 404 error.
Test log:
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6386981Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.522Z] Added WorkerConfig for language: dotnet-isolated
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6387400Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.536Z] Loading functions metadata
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6387779Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.536Z] Reading functions metadata
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6388138Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.536Z] Reading functions metadata
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6388474Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.536Z] 0 functions found
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6388790Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.536Z] 0 functions found
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6389109Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.544Z] 0 functions loaded
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6389553Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.555Z] Adding Function descriptor provider for language dotnet-isolated.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6389969Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.556Z] Creating function descriptors.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6390314Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.560Z] Function descriptors created.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6390681Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.564Z] Placeholder mode is enabled: False
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6391065Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.564Z] RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher received no functions
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6391555Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.566Z] Generating 0 job function(s)
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6392290Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.579Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6393002Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z] HttpOptions
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6393300Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z] {
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6393623Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6393995Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z]   "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6394369Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6394731Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6395080Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6395388Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.586Z] }
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6395713Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.587Z] Initializing function HTTP routes
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6396052Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.587Z] No HTTP routes mapped
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6396356Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.587Z] 
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6396667Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.596Z] Host initialized (70ms)
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6396992Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.598Z] Host started (80ms)
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6397315Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.598Z] Job host started
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6397747Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.600Z] Debug file watch initialized.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6398116Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.600Z] Diagnostic file watch initialized.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6398435Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:54.600Z] Hosting started
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6398757Z        For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6399082Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.635Z] Executing HTTP request: {
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6399452Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.635Z]   requestId: "c2e326b1-38b2-47b6-b43f-d8c0dabe7932",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6399814Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.635Z]   method: "GET",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6400127Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.635Z]   userAgent: "(null)",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6400446Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.636Z]   uri: "/"
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6400739Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.636Z] }
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6401036Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.713Z] Executed HTTP request: {
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6401401Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.713Z]   requestId: "c2e326b1-38b2-47b6-b43f-d8c0dabe7932",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6401758Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.713Z]   identities: "",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6402061Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.714Z]   status: "200",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6402373Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.714Z]   duration: "77"
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6402673Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:55.714Z] }
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6403043Z        [2024-10-29T05:53:59.584Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A4E8D433'.
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6403432Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.192Z] Executing HTTP request: {
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6403802Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.192Z]   requestId: "feb1a9b1-9f4c-411f-b7e3-61f09b74ef30",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6404158Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   method: "POST",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6404474Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   userAgent: "(null)",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6404811Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   uri: "/api/StartFunction"
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6405111Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z] }
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6405426Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z] Executed HTTP request: {
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6405856Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   requestId: "feb1a9b1-9f4c-411f-b7e3-61f09b74ef30",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6406210Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   identities: "",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6406691Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.193Z]   status: "404",
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6407002Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.194Z]   duration: "0"
2024-10-29T05:54:00.6407297Z        [2024-10-29T05:54:00.194Z] }

Configuration:
Configuration
Program class:
namespace Functions
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddOptions<FunctionOptions>()
                    .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) => configuration.GetSection("DB").Bind(settings));
            services.AddScoped<IValidator<Request>, RequestValidator>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();
        })
        .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}

Function trigger:
[Function("StartFunction")] public async Task<HttpResponseData> StartFunction( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData request, [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient orchestrationClient) { // functionality }

Integration test hook:
[Binding]
public class FunctionPerScenarioHook
{
    [BeforeScenario("startFunctionPerScenario")]
    public static Task StartFunctionsAsync(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("IntegrationTests.settings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        FunctionsController functionsController = FunctionsBindings.GetFunctionsController(scenarioContext);
        FunctionConfiguration functionConfiguration = FunctionsBindings.GetFunctionConfiguration(scenarioContext);
        functionConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables["AzureWebJobsStorage"] = config.GetValue<string>("AzureWebJobsStorage") ?? string.Empty;
        functionConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables["DB:AccountEndpoint"] = config.GetSection("DB").GetValue<string>("AccountEndpoint") ?? string.Empty;
        functionConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables["DB:CollectionName"] = config.GetSection("DB").GetValue<string>("CollectionName") ?? string.Empty;
        functionConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables["DB:DatabaseName"] = config.GetSection("DB").GetValue<string>("DatabaseName") ?? string.Empty;
        functionConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables["FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"] = config.GetValue<string>("FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME") ?? string.Empty;
        return functionsController.StartFunctionsInstance(
             "Functions",
             9697,
             "net8.0",
             configuration: functionConfiguration);
    }
}

I have tried downgrading packages, redeploying code but it did not work.

What pipeline are you using? Are you publishing using GitHub Actions?
